# Central Air is Blowing cold air outside

Tags: hvac

I change the capacitor and cleaned all of the coils inside the interior unit and outside along with the fins and the blades with a professional solution. I had the HVAC refrigerant filled. I cleaned the water pump which circulates the outgoing water  which was filthy. I also replaced the thermostat I don’t know what else it could be but the compressor.

Why would the unit still be running with a compressor that is not working? And also is there a way to check it without replacing it to see if it actually bad?

By the way the electric dryer vent is located directly above the outside unit. Why would anybody put it there is beyond my comprehension?

Comment: Is this a heat pump?  If so you may have disturbed the wiring to the reversing valve, which is usually next to the compressor.

Comment: To answer your add-on question, the dryer vent would have little impact on the compressor function. It won't affect the temperature of the air drawn through the cooling fins significantly.

Comment: Phil G , It is an electric a/c -heat pump. You think I may have disturbed wiring in the outside unit? A few days ago at least the coils  in the interior of the unit were cold.  Today I ran it all day while I was at work with two window units  and the interior coils are not cold at all. Please pardon me this is the first time I’ve used this app. Thank you!

Comment: I will check that now as I have company coming this weekend a good time for the AC to malfunction ! Thank you so much I’ll give you a update!

Comment: Actually it’s electric a/c gas furnace!  Im delusional after 5 days of trouble shooting

Comment: @isherwood the heat from the vent would not be an issue, but I had a similar setup, the  condenser was extremely effective at picking up all the lint from the dryer vent, and was completely clogged over 50% of its area,

Comment: Yes. It’s the most awkward place for a dryer vent/a/c. I am planning to put an extension on the dryer vent to release the heat away from the a/c. I put up my white flag on the a/c . I’ll be calling a certified technician shortly. It aggregates me when I can’t figure something out. I’m done. Too complicated. At least I know everything is clean!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very confused. Title about blowing cold air outside, the body talks about cleaning and servicing the interior unit, asks about a non-functioning compressor, then asks about a dryer vent. What was the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the unit was working somewhat fine and you were simply doing much appreciated maintenance to restore its past performance, then you mixed up the wiring during the new thermostat install.

If the unit wasn't cooling and therefore prompted the maintenance, then it would likely be that the TXV (Thermal Expansion Valve) needs to be replaced.

If the unit's inside coil was hot, then the Thermostat wiring is screwy...assuming it's set to Cool and not Heat. If the inside coil wasn't hot, then the Thermostat is still wrong, but you fortunately discovered before heating season that the Reversing Valve needs to be replaced.